# extract a parent node if a specific child node does not exist using XML::LIB in perl

Tags: perl, xpath

For example, my XML code is:

```xml
<part> 
      <name>qwe</name>
      <ir>
          <d>yes</d>
          <scalar>
              <left>31</left>
              <right>0</right>
          </scalar>
      </ir>
</part>
<part> 
      <name>qaz</name>
      <ir>
          <d>yes</d>
          <scalar>
              <left>1</left>
              <right>0</right>
          </scalar>
      </ir>
</part>
<part>
      <name>asd</name>
      <ir>
          <d>yes</d>
          <drive>
              <default>1</default>
          </drive>
      </ir>
</part>
<part> 
      <name>zxc</name>
      <ir>
          <d>no</d>
          <scalar>
              <left>3</left>
              <right>0</right>
          </scalar>
          <drive>
              <default>0</default>
          </drive>
      </ir>
</part>
```

I want to extract all the names which don't have a node default, i.e. the output should be `qwe, qaz` in this example. You have to check the value of default value if it is 0 or 1 and print that `asd` has default 0 and `zzxc` has default 1. if it doesn't exist print that `qwe` has no default and `qaz` has no default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default is always in `ir/drive`, you can just use the following XPath expression:

```
//part[not(ir/drive/default)]/name/text()
```

Comment: how can i get all the names of the nodes using foreach statement and get the required printed statements according to the node value.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question. Also, changing the original question several times does not help us help you.